# How can I make sure my scrollView scrolls past the height of KeyboardSpacer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I’m working on a comments page with a post container (showing the post itself) and a listView beneath rendering the comments at the bottom of the screen. Just underneath is a textInput with a keyboardspacer. It’ll bump up when a user types a post. All that works fine.

The whole screen is wrapped in a scrollView.

I basically want to have the scrollView automatically scroll down to the bottom of the screen to show a users comment, after they’ve clicked ‘send'

I’ve found this issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8003 that explains the solution.

This the solution after I implemented it:

```
class Comments extends Component {
  contentHeight = 0;
  scrollViewHeight = 0;
  scrollToBottom(animated = true) {
    const scrollHeight = this.contentHeight - this.scrollViewHeight;
    if (scrollHeight > 0) {
     const scrollResponder = this.refs.scrollView.getScrollResponder();
     scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollTo({ x: 0, scrollHeight, animated });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView
          ref='scrollView'
          onContentSizeChange={(w, h) => this.contentHeight = h}
          onLayout={ev => this.scrollViewHeight = ev.nativeEvent.layout.height}
        >
          <PostSection />
          <CommentList />
        </ScrollView>
        <CommentBar
          scrollToBottom={this.scrollToBottom.bind(this)}
        />
        <KeyboardSpacer />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I just changed it to class extends component etc

However, this behavior, for some reason actually programmatically scrolls to the TOP, which is the opposite of what it said it would do.

So I changed line 10 from

```
scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollTo({ x: 0, scrollHeight, animated });
```

to

```
scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollTo({ x: 0, y: scrollHeight, animated });
```

basically, I just added `y: scrollHeight` instead of `scrollHeight` on it’s own.

This time it scrolls down but it scrolls down TOO far.

[image]

It’ll add all that white space at the bottom. Is there anything glaringly obvious that I’m missing?

I'm thinking this must be because of the keyboard spacer I'm using as the amount of white space looks the right height of the spacer.

How can I work around this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, your comments are inserted at the top of the ListView when post button clicked. In new version of react native the method 'scrollTo(options: {x: number = 0; y: number = 0; animated: boolean = true})' is recommended to use for scrolling programmatically. You should pass 0 for y value then it would scroll to top of the scrollView on keyboard dismiss.

You are using 'KeyboardSpacer' then your scrollToBottom method has been calling first before updating actual scrollViewHeight. At the same time your scrollViewHeight is

scrollViewHeight = initialScrollViewHeight - keyBoardHeight

then the value of scrollHeight in formula

const scrollHeight = this.contentHeight - this.scrollViewHeight;

would greater than expected, thats why more white space is appearing at bottom of your scrollView.

If this is not working even after putting the value of y by 0 in scrollTo method then I recommended to use IQKeyboardManager library for iOS. It handles all the scroll behaviours itself you do not code anywhere by yourself. Thanks!